# Error to add product

Tags: magento2, admin, http-error-500

In my admin area when I click on add product, I am directed to a screen with error 500, in my log, I have the following message

> "[2020-05-29 14:54:03] main.INFO: Broken reference: the
>   'product.reviews' the element cannot be added as a child to
>   'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

What could have happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Ran the query on my magento database: SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE source_model LIKE "%Temando%"

Set the 3 values to "NULL".

Now I can edit products again.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318269/57334 any help thanks @Hudson Alves Triunfante