# Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, database, php-7.4

Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please check this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/313955/85907

Comment: Set the 3 values to "NULL" didnt understand bro